# JavaScript 'Image Copy' does not trigger copy event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm handling with JavaScript's copy event. Handling with plain text works as I expected.

But observed that the 'image copy' or 'copy link address' of mouse left click menu does not trigger copy event in chrome.

Is there any way that I could trigger some event by image copy, or copy link address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check This [Link](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#security):

> Enabling authors to change what is copied by a user, or to make an automated copy of something that was never selected and allowing unrestricted calls to paste information can raise various security concerns.
>
> Some example scenarios include:
>
> A user selects a link and copies it, but a different link is copied to
> the clipboard. The effect of this can range from an unexpected result
> on pasting to an attempted "phishing" attack.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. Copying text or pressing Ctrl+C on a page triggers Javascript events, which can be used to manipulate clipboard contents. For some reason copying an image does not.